# R Delete rows with multiple NULLs (edited)

Tags: r, null, delete-row

I have a very large data frame with hundreds of variables.  I want to delete rows where there is a NULL for variables that are in consecutive columns.  The data frame, df, looks something like this:

```
ID     V1     V2    V3    V4    V5   V6    V7    V8    V9    V10    V11     V12
ABC    1      2     3     4     1    2     3     NULL  4      1     AB      BC
DEF    2      3     NULL  4     2    3     4     1     2      3     AB      BC
GHI    NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL   AB      BC
JKL    3      4     1     2     3    4     1     2     3      4     AB      BC
MNO    1      2     3     4     1    NULL  2     3     4      1     AB      BC
```

In this data frame, I want to delete ONLY row df$ID=="GHI" for example, so I get:

```
ID     V1     V2    V3    V4    V5   V6    V7    V8    V9    V10    V11     V12
ABC    1      2     3     4     1    2     3     NULL  4      1     AB      BC
DEF    2      3     NULL  4     2    3     4     1     2      3     AB      BC
JKL    3      4     1     2     3    4     1     2     3      4     AB      BC
MNO    1      2     3     4     1    NULL  2     3     4      1     AB      BC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Anything you tried? Why did it not work?

Comment: I've tried df <- df[!is.null(df$V1) & !is.null(df$V2) & ... ,] as well as df <- df[!(df$V1==is.null & df$V2==is.null & ... ,] among other methods that haven't worked.

Comment: Should all rows with multiple NULLs be deleted, or only rows where all values in certain columns are NULL, or rows with for instance 1, NULL, 1?

Comment: I want to delete only the rows (like GHI) where there is NULL for variables V1-V10.

Comment: You need to look up the definition of 'consecutive' before asking people to do program it as a solution.

Comment: @PierreLafortune: Yes. Consecutive. An adjective meaning in an unbroken sequence.  In this case, V1-V10 have NULL values, and they are consecutive.  Where is the misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't spoonfeed it to you. If you don't understand the difference between all NULL and consecutive NULL then I doubt you will get it anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a job for `rle()`.

```
a <- !apply(df[paste0("V", 1:10)] == "NULL", 1, function(x) {
    with(rle(x), any(lengths[values] > 1))
})

df[a, ]
#    ID V1 V2   V3 V4 V5   V6 V7   V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
# 1 ABC  1  1    1  1  1    1  1 NULL  1   1  AB  BC
# 2 DEF  1  1 NULL  1  1    1  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
# 4 JKL  1  1    1  1  1    1  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
# 5 MNO  1  1    1  1  1 NULL  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"), V1 = c("1", 
"1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V2 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V3 = c("1", 
"NULL", "NULL", "1", "1"), V4 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), 
    V5 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V6 = c("1", "1", "NULL", 
    "1", "NULL"), V7 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V8 = c("NULL", 
    "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V9 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"
    ), V10 = c("1", "1", "NULL", "1", "1"), V11 = c("AB", "AB", 
    "AB", "AB", "AB"), V12 = c("BC", "BC", "BC", "BC", "BC")), .Names = c("ID", 
"V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", 
"V11", "V12"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: This is most likely the best way to go

Comment: I brute-forced it.  See below.

Comment: I followed your directions and read all the comments.  See above.

Answer (score 1):

One can use rowSums to count the occurrences of "NULL" and subset the dataframe by retaining only those rows with at most one NULL:

```
newdf <- df1[rowSums(df1=="NULL")<2,]
#> newdf
#   ID V1 V2   V3 V4 V5   V6 V7   V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
#1 ABC  1  2    3  4  1    2  3 NULL  4   1  AB  BC
#2 DEF  2  3 NULL  4  2    3  4    1  2   3  AB  BC
#4 JKL  3  4    1  2  3    4  1    2  3   4  AB  BC
#5 MNO  1  2    3  4  1 NULL  2    3  4   1  AB  BC
```

**data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="ID     V1     V2    V3    V4    V5   V6    V7    V8    V9    V10    V11     V12
ABC    1      2     3     4     1    2     3     NULL  4      1     AB      BC
DEF    2      3     NULL  4     2    3     4     1     2      3     AB      BC
GHI    NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL   AB      BC
JKL    3      4     1     2     3    4     1     2     3      4     AB      BC
MNO    1      2     3     4     1    NULL  2     3     4      1     AB      BC", 
header=TRUE)
```

Comment: When I put this to newdf <- df1[rowSums(df1=="NULL")<2,], it returned a data frame that appeared to delete those rows, but everything else is the new data frame is now NA.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything else"? Does newdf look different from the output I posted? I tried with your data and I didn't get NAs.

Comment: In my newdf, the variables stay the same.  However, all row names now become NA, NA.1, NA.2, NA.3, etc., and all the values for each row under each variable is NA.  I'm not sure why your solution isn't working.

Comment: Can't confirm the error. Please double-check if you typed everything correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I've edited my original question.  That probably has something to do with why I'm getting the results I'm getting (i.e., the values for V1-V10 have multiple values, not just "1").

Comment: I don't think this should be a problem. The code only counts the occurrences of "NULL" in each row and it should not modify the data, apart from the logical subsetting.

Comment: This doesn't account for cases where the NULL values might be in two columns in the same row, but not next to each other, does it?  It just looks for less than 2 NULLs per row

Comment: @RichardScriven The way I see it, your rle solution accounts for consecutive NULLs, as (I assume) the one by @ noname does. This one just counts the number of NULLs in each row, very similar to the approach by @ DatamineR.

Comment: So what exactly is OP trying to do here?  Haha

Comment: I brute-forced it with df <- df[!(df$V1=="NULL" &
              df$V2=="NULL" &
              df$V3=="NULL" &
              ... &
              df$V20=="NULL"),]

Comment: Guess I'm just having a slow day :)

Comment: @Orion - that removes rows where they are **all** NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want *consecutive* NA or NULL, then you can try,

```
df[-which(apply( df, 1, function(x) { seq<-which(is.na(x)); ifelse(any(diff(seq)==1),TRUE,FALSE) } )),]
```

Otherwise use the sum method.

Comment: The sum method deleted rows, but returned a new data frame full of NAs with none of the pre-existing values.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
df[!apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(sapply(x, function(x) x == "NULL"))>1),]
   ID V1 V2   V3 V4 V5   V6 V7   V8 V9 V10 V11 V12
1 ABC  1  1    1  1  1    1  1 NULL  1   1  AB  BC
2 DEF  1  1 NULL  1  1    1  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
4 JKL  1  1    1  1  1    1  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
5 MNO  1  1    1  1  1 NULL  1    1  1   1  AB  BC
```

Comment: The code calculates the sum of `NULL`s for every row and checks where it is over 1 and then drops the rows where it is greater than 1. So, if I understand you correctly, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: Still don' need to change it. Does the code work for you?